# gdb print char* as string characters

Tags: gdb

```
char* buf;
...

(gdb) x/s buf
0x7fffef8f5f80: "35=DC\001\064\071=ABCD\001"

(gdb) x/12cb buf
0x7fffef8f5f80: 51 '3'  53 '5'  61 '='  65 'D'  66 'C'  1 '\001'        52 '4'  57 '9'
0x7fffef8f5f88: 61 '='  83 'A'  80 'B'  88 'C'  84 'D'  1 '\001'
```

Question> How can I enable gdb to print the buf as the following:

`"35=DC\00149=ABCD\001"`?

Thank you

Comment: How do you determine the length of the string?  I do not see a null terminator.

Comment: I know the length because I write the buf manually. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question> How can I enable gdb to print the buf as the following:

There is no way to do this right now.  You could file a gdb bug report if you like.

What is going on here is that gdb's string-printing function has a special case to escape a digit when it follows a character that was emitted as an escape sequence.  That is why you see `\064` and not `4`.